# PostgreSQL group by then count by value

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

I have the following data

```
id | sub_id |status |
---|--------|-------|
1  |    1   | new   |
2  |    2   | old   |
3  |    2   | new   |
4  |    3   | old   |
```

Which query should I use to get the following result?
I want to group the result by `sub_id` and then add new columns that store the number of statuses of the corresponding `sub_id`.

```
sub_id | new  | old  | total |
-------|------|------|-------|
1      |  1   | 0    |  1    |
2      |  1   | 1    |  2    |
3      |  0   | 1    |  1    |
```

I tried this and it did not work as expected.

```
SELECT 
  sub_id, 
  count(status='new') AS new, 
  count(status='old') AS old,
  count(status) AS total
FROM table
GROUP BY sub_id;
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner PostgreSQL, thank you, your answer works.

Comment: I'm glad it does. For the future: Always tag SQL requests with the DBMS. And "it did not work as expected" is a very bad way to tell us about the issue. Please tell us in what way this does not work. Do you get a syntax error? Are the figures too high or too low? Do you get more or less rows than expected? Don't let us guess. (Though guessing was easy here :-)

Comment: `count(*) filter (where status = 'new')`

Comment: By"it did not work as expected" I meant unexpected output, which you explain to me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`status = 'new'` is

- true for all rows with `status = 'new'`
- false for all rows with `status <> 'new'`
- null for all rows with `status is null`.

`COUNT( <expression> )` counts all non-null occurences of the expression. This means you count both `'new'` and `'old'`, as neither true nor false is null, when you only want to count `'new'`. Use a `CASE` expression instead:

```
count(case when status = 'new' then 1 end)
```

which is short for

```
count(case when status = 'new' then 1 else null end)
```

or the same with `SUM`:

```
sum(case when status = 'new' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Some DBMS (MySQL for instance) treat true as 1 and false as 0. There you can even use:

```
sum(status = 'new')
```

In PostgreSQL you can also use the `filter()` clause:

```
count(*) filter (where status = 'new')
```

Comment: You left out `sum( (status = 'new')::int )`, which is Postgres specific and still quite useful (if you are using `avg()` for instance).